# Sorting a linked list with alternate elements sorted and reverse sorted

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I was asked this in an interview.

The list looks like this.

a<sub>1</sub>->b<sub>n</sub>->a<sub>2</sub>->b<sub>n-1</sub> ... ->a<sub>n</sub>->b<sub>1</sub>->NULL

Such that, 
a<sub>1</sub> < a<sub>2</sub> < ... < a<sub>n</sub>

and

b<sub>1</sub> < b<sub>2</sub> < ... < b<sub>n</sub>

The interviewer put following constrains on me:

1. You have to sort the list in place, that is you are not allowed to
   remove the alternate elements of a group of elements into a separate
   list.
2. You have to somehow make use of the pattern that is there in the list than a naive, sorting algorithm.

I could not come up with the solution during the interview and now too. :-(

Edit  : Write code in C to sort this singly linked list.

Edit2 : It was also told to me that I can borrow some idea from bubble sort and take advantage of the pattern. But it should not be a "naive" short.

I hate when interviewer puts artificial constrains but hey job is a job :-)

Comment: So, what is the desired result? That the list as a whole be sorted, without distinction between the `a` and `b` elements?

Comment: Edited the question to address the comments

Comment: @Saurabh You haven't addressed my question. What is the desired output?

Comment: I have. The question was already answered though : You have to sort the list in place,

Comment: @Saurabh Actually, no. All you have said is that the list should be "sorted". You haven't specified whether that means that there should be no distinction between the `a` and `b` nodes.

Comment: Also, what's a "naive" sort? One would normally take that to mean one that has worse performance than nlogn in the average case.

Comment: If you are not allowed to shuffle the list by altering the pointers, then why have a linked list in the first place? The restriction is perverse, and complying with it would not get you the job, if I were the interviewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You have to sort the list in place" this requirement confuses me. I'd have thought that the natural solution is:

- by jiggering the "next" pointers in the list, create two lists. One contains the a's, and the other contains the b's, reversed.
- do a merge on those two lists.

But I'm not sure whether the first step breaks the rule. It *is* "in place" as I understand the term, since it doesn't copy the nodes or their data, and in fact it doesn't move any data either. But it *does* remove the alternate elements into a separate list.

I can't immediately think how to combine the two steps into a single pass.

[Edit: maybe "in place" here means that we *should* move the data, rather than relinking the list. In which case I think the problem is harder: efficient in-place merge sort is painful enough in an array, without trying to do it (a) on a linked list, (b) with alternate elements in the wrong order]

Comment: Steve, this was my first reaction to the problem also, but as per the interviewer it was a requirement.

Comment: @Saurabh: well, if you're not allowed to re-link the nodes then a linked list is just like an array without random-access. So the solution will be the same as for an array, but probably slower.

Comment: I think that is what he meant. I will accept your answer. Jeesh I am embarrassed now :D

Comment: I think a further improvement was to first sort the alternate elements in place which are reverse sorted. And then merge the two lists which are sorted.

Comment: @Saurabh: the mention of bubble sort reminds me that bubble sort is the optimal sort for an access pattern in which you can see memory through a small window that tracks forward but not backward, then starts again at the beginning (rotating drum storage). A singly-linked list is just like that, it's cheap to move forward but to move back you have to start from the beginning. I haven't yet thought of a way to optimize bubble sort for this input data thought.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep it "in place", you can first transform the list in-place to

a<sub>1</sub> -> ... -> a<sub>n</sub> -> b<sub>1</sub> -> ... -> b<sub>n</sub>

by walking through the list and moving the b elements to the end of the list one by one.

After this, you can then move the a elements forwards one by one in a "bubble-sort fashion", i.e. scanning forwards until you find their place after the boundary that's initially before b<sub>1</sub>.

However I agree that the question is rather artificial.